# Keeping values entered in template

Tags: underscore.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

In my underscore/marionette application, there's an interaction that involves switching between the radio buttons.

When switching back I need to keep the entered form value.

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
    var myView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: _.template(MyView2),
        data: {
            template1: "",
        },
        ui: {
            region1: "#region1",
            textDiv: "#template1",
        },
        events: {
            'click #txt-input-type input:radio': 'changedRadio'
        },
        onShow: function (view, region, options) {
            //After Render 
            this.data.template1 = _.template($(this.ui.textDiv).html(), {});
            this.$el.find(this.ui.region1).html(this.data.template1);
        },

        changedRadio: function (evt) {
            var self = this;
            var checkedObject = evt.currentTarget;
            if (checkedObject.value === "file") {
                //FileTemplate for upload: here file will get reset
            } else if (checkedObject.value === "text") {
                //Load TextBox Template here it is resetting previous:  entered value;              
                this.$el.find(this.ui.region1).html(this.data.template1);
            }
        });
    return myView;

}
```

In the above code, when switching between radio buttons, the values entered in the `textDiv` will get reset.

How to re-render the template to keep the values?

Comment: more info, please: enclose your templates as well. also, why do you need re-render the template on switch?

Comment: @EliranMalka I am having two template which need to be load on radio button change. Like giving option to upload through file or entering into textbox. But if i switch the previous entered value getting reset.